# How to assign a group to a user in PHP

Tags: user-groups

The following doesn't assign an existing user to a group. I've confirmed that both the user and the group exist. Any ideas?

```
$user = User::find()->username($username)->one();
$user->setGroups([Craft::$app->userGroups->getGroupById(1)]);
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($user);
```

I found [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/saving-assigning-user-group-via-a-plugin), which will probably solve it for me, but it leaves me wondering what the purpose of `setGroups` is.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is the right way to do it:

```
$user = User::find()->username($username)->one();
Craft::$app->users->assignUserToGroups($user->id, [1]);
```

It's unclear how `setGroups` is supposed to work.